# Does updating a browser's software clear the cache?

Tags: html, css, caching

What happens to the cache when you update the browser's software?

For example: I am hosting a bit of code on a 3rd party website that contains logo image embedded in the code. If the host changes the logo and I clear the cache, the new logo appears. So, if I update the browser, will the cache naturally get cleared (and display the new logo) or does will it stay maintained with logo it had prior?

Comment: sometimes but I always do this http://pcsupport.about.com/od/browsers/f/clear-cache.htm

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you update your browser, normally you would "force clear cache" for the chached data (e.g. ctrl + f5 for Windows or cmd + R for Mac). If you don't do that you potentially can see your old logo.